# How to pass NULL in where array for $wpdb->update

Tags: wpdb

how to get results of a row with NULL element?
I have to update the row which contains only the post_id and the repeat value, 'start' and 'end' should be NULL

mysql table screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6pmA.png

```
$wpdb->update( $schedule_table, array( 'rpt' => $event_tag ), array( 'post_id' => $post_ID, 'start' => NULL, 'end' => NULL ), array( '%s' ) );
$wpdb->print_error();
```

I get this error:

WordPress database error: [] UPDATE `wp_MW_3_schedule` SET `rpt` = 'monday' WHERE `post_id` = 357 AND `start` = '' AND `end` = ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My simple and quick solution is the use of a normal $wpdb->query() function:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $schedule_table SET rpt = %s WHERE post_id = %d AND start IS NULL AND end IS NULL", $event_tag, $post_ID ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this ticket's comment](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15158#comment:46), `NULL` format is now working correctly and you can write your query as:

```
$wpdb->update(
    $schedule_table, 
    array('rpt' => $event_tag), 
    array('post_id' => $post_ID, 'start' => NULL, 'end' => NULL), 
    array('%s'), 
    array('%d', NULL, NULL) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL is a php construct with special meaning, you should have probably used "NULL" instead.

```
$wpdb->update( $schedule_table, array( 'rpt' => $event_tag ), array( 'post_id' => $post_ID, 'start' => 'NULL', 'end' => 'NULL' ), array( '%s' ) );
```

Comment: No, it does not work either.

Comment: interesting, do you know what is the actual query being sent?

Comment: It's: WordPress database error: [] UPDATE wp_MW_3_schedule SET rpt = 'monday' WHERE post_id = 357 AND start = 'NULL' AND end = 'NULL'

Comment: maybe WordPress tries to sanitize and adds the "'" around NULL. If that is the case then your your use of query is probably the only way to do it

Comment: I guess so but thank you anyways for your support! _Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!_

Comment: just for reference there is a trac ticket for that http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12819